# Error EOF Syntax Error

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, debugging

`-bash: /Users/tj/.bash_profile: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

This is currently at the top of my terminal window. I need to fix this error. I have deleted the last line out of my bash file. Here's what it looks like:

```
export OAUTHHOME=/Users/tj/OAuth export PATH=$PATH:$OAUTHHOME alias oauth-header="java -jar $OAUTHHOME/auth-header-1.4.jar -k 5370283b-9658-47b4-9112- -s Y4Hrx9q5YCHM_ -p https://oauth/access -c"

eval "$(rbenv init -)" if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion   fi/Users/tj/.bash_profile

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}" export PATH

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function* 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: At least as presented here, there are a number of missing line breaks here, and the given file doesn't have 17 lines. Especially when asking about syntax errors, it's critical to give the file accurately, so readers don't have to guess which syntax errors are in the original, and which were added by misformatting it. Please edit your question to list the file's contents accurately.

Answer (score 3):

1. It’s disturbing that you present a 10-line file
   along with an error message that refers to line 17.
2. I don’t fully understand the `eval "$(rbenv init -)" if` construct
   on the third line.

But the obvious errors are on the fourth line:

- `fi/Users/tj/.bash_profile` should be `fi`, and
- there should be a `;` before it (or it should be on a separate line).

Comment: 1. It's not formatted right within my question to show that there are 17 lines.
2. I believe that was a line I found for rbenv

I'm new to bash_profile things so the error wasn't so obvious for me. Thanks for the help